# Question about disconnected metric spaces

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

The definition of disconnectedness that I've been taught is that a metric space $(X,d)$ is disconnected if there exists two non-empty disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$ such that $X=A\cup B$.

My question is, if $X$ is a disconnected metric space and you were to take $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then is the distance $d(a,b)$ between them a valid operation? If so, what would this distance be?

More concretely, if you were to have something like $X=[0,3) \cup (4,8]$ with the standard metric for $\mathbb{R}$, then what is $d(2,5)$ in $X$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The metric on the subspace is just the restriction of the metric from the original space. So $d(2,5)$ in the space you've written is $3$. There is not much you can say that is special about this situation from the metric point of view. One thing you can say is that if $A,B$ are as above and $d(a,b)$ is bounded below for $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, then $X$ is disconnected. But the converse is not true; $(0,1) \cup (1,2)$ is disconnected.